# How do I find the x and z rotation of the firstpersoncontroller in Ursina?

Tags: python

I need to find out the players rotation angles in a demo game I am making. Problem is, when I do this:

```
print(player.rotation_x, player.rotation_y, player.rotation_z)
```

It only shows rotation_y, and not the other two.

I then tried the same thing with camera.rotation_x:

```
print(camera.rotation_x, camera.rotation_y, camera.rotation_z)
```

which would normally work but because I am using FirstPersonController just returns

```
0.0, 0.0, 0.0
```

Is there anyway I can find out the rotation angle of the FirstPersonController?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found out the answer by checking the source code of Ursina Engine.

Basically, the FirstPersonController works by using

```
self.camera_pivot
```

so instead of using

```
player.rotation_x, player.rotation_y, player.rotation_z
```

you have to use

```
player.camera_pivot.rotation_x, player.camera_pivot.rotation_y, player.camera_pivot.rotation_z
```

the only exception to this is

```
player.rotation_y
```

which will still work